# Execute Scan command after scanning item in acumatica 2023 r1

Tags: acumatica, barcode-scanner

I have requirement where I need to allow users to enter qty in pick pack ship and other similar barcode scanning forms e.g. PO302020, IN301020, IN304020,IN305020, SO302020. By default acumatica is setting picked/received qty =1 in the details grid , after scanning item.

So I have two requirements here

1. Set the default scan qty=0 in the grid below.
2. Allow user to manually enter qty, by firing SET QTY command immediately after scanning item

For this default scan qty  = 0, I figured that out but with some bugs. Below is my code for the same.

```
protected void POReceiptLineSplit_ReceivedQty_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      
      var row = (POReceiptLineSplit)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            if (row.ReceivedQty == 1)
            {
                row.ReceivedQty = 0;
            }
        }

    

    #endregion
  }
```

But I am unable to figure the way to execute SET QTY command as per the requirement. Please help. I am an absolute beginner to Acumatica. Any code block or close reference will work.